# Generics : run-time ADT for types with instances

Tags: haskell

Is it possible with Haskell / GHC, to extract an algebraic data type representing all types with Eq and Ord instances ?  This would probably need Generics, Typeable, etc.

What I would like is something like :

```
data Data_Eq_Ord = Data_String String 
                 | Data_Int Int
                 | Data_Bool Bool
                 | ...
deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

For all types known to have instances for Eq and Ord. If it makes the solution easier, we can limit our scope to Ord instances, since Eq is implied by Ord. But is would be interesting to know if constraints intersection is possible.

This data type would be useful because it gives the possibility to use it where Eq and Ord constraints are required, and pattern-match at runtime to refine on types.

I would need this to implement a generic Map Key Value, where Key would be this type, in a Document Indexing library, where the keys and their type is known at run-time. This library is [here](https://github.com/PaulRivier/kiwi/blob/master/src/Utils/DocIndex.hs). For the moment I worked around the issue by defining a `data DocIndexKey`, and a `FieldKey` class, but this is not fully satisfactory since it requires boilerplate and can't cover all legit candidates.

Any good alternative approach to this situation is welcome. For some reasons, I prefer to avoid Template Haskell.

Comment: My first thought is whether you can use `Data.Typeable` and/or `Data.Dynamic` for this...

Comment: Generics and Typeable are definitely not going to get you there. Typeclasses are by design _open_, i.e. it's always possible to add more instances later on. So `Data_Eq_Ord` could never be guaranteed to be complete. _Maybe_ it's possible with TH do get all the instances that are _currently in scope_, but I'm not sure about even that. — I'd say your best bet is probably to use `TypeRep`s as keys into a conceptually infinite, lazy `MemoTrie` structure or something.

Comment: When compilation is terminated, no more instances can be added, so at some point the compiler knows what instances of Ord are defined over the whole program.  That said, there is a challenge in the modules compilation sequence indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not an ADT, but this definitely works:

```
data Satisfying c = forall a. c a => Satisfy a
class (l a, r a) => And l r a where
instance (l a, r a) => And l r a where

ex :: [Satisfying (Typeable `And` Show `And` Ord)]
ex = [ Satisfy (7 :: Int)
     , Satisfy "Hello"
     , Satisfy (5 :: Int)
     , Satisfy [10..20 :: Int]
     , Satisfy ['a'..'z']
     , Satisfy ((), 'a')]

-- An example of use, with "complicated" logic
data With f c = forall a. c a => With (f a)
--                 vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv QuantifiedConstraints chokes on this, which is probably a bug...
partitionTypes :: (forall a. c a => TypeRep a) -> [Satisfying c] -> [[] `With` c]
partitionTypes rep = foldr go []
   where go (Satisfy x) [] = [With [x]]
         go x'@(Satisfy (x :: a)) (xs'@(With (xs :: [b])) : xss) =
             case testEquality rep rep :: Maybe (a :~: b) of
                 Just Refl -> With (x : xs) : xss
                 Nothing -> xs' : go x' xss

main :: IO ()
main = traverse_ (\(With xs) -> print (sort xs)) $ partitionTypes typeRep ex
```

Exhaustivity is much harder. Perhaps with a plugin, you could get GHC to do it, but why bother? I don't believe GHC actually tries to keep track of what types it has seen. In particular, you'd have to scan all modules in the project and its dependencies, even those that haven't been loaded by the module containing the type definition. You'd have to implement it from the ground-up. And, as this answer shows, I very much doubt you would actually be able to *use* such exhaustivity for anything that you can't already do by just taking the open universe as it is.

Comment: This is an interesting take on the subject, and although it is not exactly the solution I hoped to find, this demonstrates very advanced typing techniques that can be useful for similar situations. Thank you very much !